# Count buffered streets that intersect buffered points using PostGIS

Tags: performance, sql, postgresql, geospatial

PostgreSQL 9.5.1 with PostGIS 2.0 extension

This first section creates an intersection (clip) of the streets from another polygon (MTC15), then it buffers the intersection:

```
with   cte_intersection as (select st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) as geom from public.streets a, public."MTC15" b 
              where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)),
       cte_buffer as (select st_buffer(geom::geography, 15.24)::geometry as geom from cte_intersection)

insert into public."MTC_MockArea"(geom) select geom from cte_buffer;
```

This query counts the instances where a buffered point feature intersects the buffered, intersected street feature:

```
select count(distinct b.gid) as ticket_count from public."MTC_MockArea" a, public."points_buffered" b
              where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom);
```

This is taking an extraordinary amount of time and I was wondering if anyone with some PostGIS knowledge could help speed up these queries. I've already created indexed/clustered/vacuumed/analyzed the tables FYI.

Comment: Did you profile using [queryplans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html)?

Comment: I looked at at the explain tab afterwards and it said the insert statement was using the most cost.

Answer (score 2):

adding this CTE decreased the time from 1 hr 11 minutes to 2 minutes 62 seconds:

```
cte_dumppoly as (select (st_dump(geom)).geom as geom, dccode from public."MTC15")
```

making the final query look like:

```
with    cte_dumppoly as (select (st_dump(geom)).geom as geom, dccode from public."MTC15"),
        cte_intersection as (select st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) as geom from public.streets a, cte_dumppoly b 
              where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)),
        cte_buffer as (select st_buffer(geom::geography, 15.24)::geometry as geom from cte_intersection)

insert into public."MTC_MockArea"(geom) select geom from cte_buffer;
```